# Application specific compile time settings in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to provide compile-time settings for my SvelteKit site to create builds with different API URLs for local development, staging and production. What is the de facto way to configuration method to

- Providing such settings
- Consuming them in components

... that would be familiar to all Svelte developers?

Answer (score 2):

the de facto way to do this in *any* framework is to use environment variables.  During development that can be done using `.env` files (which you should not commit) while in staging and production it kind of depends on your hosting service how to add these, but the concept is the same.

Example for `.env`

```
VITE_APIURL=http://localhost:1234
```

If you prepend them with `VITE_` like above you can simply do `import.meta.env.VITE_APIURL` in your code to get that value.

Comment: Excellent. The last bit of magic is especially helpful and Svelte specific.